# Finding out when MapLoader finished (eager) loading in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I use the MapLoader for initial loading data from the data store to Hazelcast (InitialLoadMode = EAGER). I need to load this data from a materialized view that is created for the sake of this loading at the beginning of this loading process and after the loading is done, I need to remove this materialized view.

Is there any way to tell Hazelcast to fire my code creating this view before it starts loading the data using MapLoader?

Is there any way to be notified by Hazelcast after the initial load is finished? I looked through listeners but I only saw those regarding the single value.

The only way I came up with is to create the materialized view in MapLoader.loadAllKeys() (it guarantees it will be executed only once and that it will be executed befor anyone can get something from the map, and so before anyone can invoke the loading process inadvertently) and then somewhere else invoke getMap("") (I use EAGER) and when it finishes, delete the entity.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: As I understood you need to load (once? on application startup?) some collection of keys using MapLoader. And you need other threads that is trying to read from the map to wait while loading to be completed. Is it correct?

Comment: I need to create database entities from which I will perform the initial load (as with MapLoader) and then remove those database entities once the load is finished. So I need to run some piece of code before the loading starts and then run another one, when the loading is finished.

Comment: the entities in database is added on application startup or by some other event?

Comment: It's a part of normal Hazelcast initial load process and I need to create those entities with regard to this process. The maps are loaded by Hazelcast using MapLoaders and they have their own lifecycle. I need to create those entities before the load begins (and it can be triggered at any time by any of the cache clients) and remove them after it ends. Also, I need to do it only once for the whole cluster and not once for each of the cluster members.

Answer (score 2):

If you need full control of your initialization process then probably you need to fill your map manually without MapLoader:

```
public class MapWrapper {

    private Lock lock = hazelcastInstance.getLock("map-lock");
    private IAtomicLong mapIsLoaded = ...;
    ICountDownLatch latch = hazelcastInstance.getCountDownLatch("map-loaded");

    public MapWrapper() {
        latch.trySetCount(1);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        lock.lock();
        // Loading:
        try {
            // Skip loading if map already loaded (ensure only once for cluster)
            if(mapIsLoaded.get() == 1) {
                return;
            }
            mapIsLoaded.set(0);
            // Here code to load your map, clean database:
            initializeDatabase();
            loadMap();
            cleanDatabase();
        } finally {
            latch.countdown();
            mapIsLoaded.set(1);
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Map getMap() {
        // Blocking until loading is completed:
        latch.await();
        return hazelcastInstance.getMap(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution, but there are some problems:
1. Embedded cluster - this will work
2. Client - server - this will not work if run on the cluster (server) side, as there will have to be additional synchronization on the client side (which makes this solution a bit cumbersome). If it was put on the client, each client using this would have to use this synchronization code also, which again makes it cumbersome. But in general it's an interesting option. I can use part of it though to enchance my original idea.

Comment: @rattaman could you please clarify point about additional synchronization on client side? Why do you need it?

Comment: Because if client calls getMap before the server finishes loading the map, he will get partial results.

Comment: @rattaman this should be handled by latch.await(); in getMap(), or I miss-understood something?

Comment: The whole synchronization bit you presented is being done on the server. So the map is locked only on the server side. If you want to use it on the client without the risk of it being partially loaded, you have to await on the same latch. So this code latch.await must be present on the client side also.

Comment: @rattaman agree, but you can have all this loading code on client side only, as I understood the clients is some java application.

Comment: Yes, but you then have to have this synchronization code on any client also, regardless of whether it does load the cache or not. Ideally I would like a solution, that would work inside Hazelcast cluster (just like loadKeys works inside the cluster and is guaranteed to run only once and I don't have to do any following synchronizations), which would work automagically.

Comment: @rattaman for your task where you need control of flow before and after loading complete you'll need synchronization. The only visible way to me is to hide this in something like helper component available for all services and reuse this component.